# Debugging php. file and line

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on an older script. Someone told me that the script uses ancient way of debugging (file and line).

I've posted an example of the script. What should I be using instead of the FILE and LINE method?

mysql class -

```
 function error($file, $line) {
            trigger_error("DB error in *<b>{$file}</b>* on line <b>{$line}</b><br />\n " . mysql_error() . "" . @mysql_error($this->dbl), E_USER_ERROR);
        }


      function query($query, $file, $line) {

            $result = mysql_query($query) or $this->error($file, $line);
            $this->num_queries++;

            return $result;
        }
```

Standard query -

```
$DB->query("SELECT * FROM table"), __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realistically, you should be using [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) for this.

Eg:

```
function error(){
    $trace = debug_backtrace();
    $file = $trace[1]['file']; // use 1 because you don't want
                               // to include this function!
                               // 2 will be the function which called the function 
                               // which called this function.
    $line = $trace[1]['line'];
    trigger_error("DB error in *<b>{$file}</b>* on line <b>{$line}</b><br />\n " . 
                  // You really should consider using MySQLi instead of MySQL
                  mysql_error() . "" . @mysql_error($this->dbl), E_USER_ERROR);
                  // why do you have two mysql_error calls???
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you show me how to replace the current function with the new one and how to call it? I'm not sure what to do...

Comment: @domino Um... you simply replace it? If you get rid of the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` arguments this should work as a stand in.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at migrating away from this custom database wrapper. The most common object oriented libraries are [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Both of these libraries support error checking.

[`MySQLi::query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) returns false on error. You can retrieve the error message through [`MySQLi::error()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

[`PDO::query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) also returns false on error. You can retrieve the erro message through [`PDO::errorInfo()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php)

Comment: This is not an answer. It should be a comment.

Comment: @cwallenpoole I don't see how this is not relevant information. He asked "What should I be using instead of the FILE and LINE method?" and this is what I recommend he does.

Comment: @cwallenpoole I actually find it quite interesting that you believe that `$DB->query("SELECT * FROM table"), __FILE__, __LINE__);` is acceptable.

Comment: @hafichuk I intend on using PDO for my next projects but I can't be bothered to recode the current one. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @hafichuk I don't think it is acceptable at all, but your answer does not look like it really addresses the question.